Автоматизация профилей octo browser с помощью selenium на chromedriver. Python
Хочу связать selenium с octo browser. На официальном сайте дана инструкция как это сделать, вот она:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1801428/UVC6i6eA#f32c145e-7327-4f88-89ad-e37e21f8eb40
Но у меня открывается два окна - собственно профиль окто и браузер хром драйвера. Должно открываться одно окно - профиль окто в котором и будет происходить автоматизация.
Кто нибудь знает в чем может быть причина? Я грешу на дебаг порт. Когда в cmd выполняю команду netscan - a, то дебаг порт там не фигурирует. Открыл на роутере порты и для роутера и для локальной машины на которой всё крутится - не помогло. Но нигде и не говорится что нужно открывать порты :)
Прилагаю свой код. Он слегка отличается от того что дан в инструкции, т.к. инициализация хромдрайвера изменилась после написания инструкции на сайте окто, думаю это не критично и причина не в этом. Прошу помощи.
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

PROFILE_ID = 'fd38a9b82a4d4748818270bfd6f31ef3'
LOCAL_API = 'http://localhost:58888/api/profiles'
#WEBDRIVERPATH = Service(
#    executable_path=r'rev/rev/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe')
LOCAL_API = 'http://localhost:58888/api/profiles'
def get_webdriver(port):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
        'debuggerAddress', f'127.0.0.1:{port}')
    # Change chrome driver path accordingly
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=WEBDRIVERPATH)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options))
    return driver
def get_debug_port(profile_id):
    data = requests.post(
        f'{LOCAL_API}/start', json={'uuid': profile_id, 'headless': False, 'debug_port': True}
    ).json()
    print(data)
    return data['debug_port']
def main():
    port = get_debug_port(PROFILE_ID)
    driver = get_webdriver(port)
    driver.get('http://amazon.com')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

